# Turn 1D list to a triangle 2D list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list made of range from 1 to 55 with step 2: `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, ..., 53]`.
What I'm trying to do is to fill another list, which is 2D and triangular, with numbers from the first list.

```
def odd_triangle(n):
    a = []
    b = []
    for number in range(1, 55, 2):
        a.append(number)
    for i in range(n):
        b.append([])
        for j in range(i+1):
            b[i].append(a[i])
    print(b)
```

After I call that function, for example `odd_triangle(5)` (5 rows will be created), it gives me not exactly what I want to:
`[[1], [3, 3], [5, 5, 5], [7, 7, 7, 7], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9]]`

What I want it to be is: `[[1], [3, 5], [7, 9, 11], [13, 15, 17, 19], [21, 23, 25, 27, 29]]`

Comment: You append `a[i]` every time. Append `a[j+i]` or something instead. If you want to append a different element each time, you need to append a different element each time.

Comment: Voting to close because typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
a = list(range(1,55,2))
n = 5
it = iter(a)
b = list([next(it) for _ in range(i)] for i in range(1, n+1))
```

Gives:

```
[[1], [3, 5], [7, 9, 11], [13, 15, 17, 19], [21, 23, 25, 27, 29]]
```

Here, `next(it)` simply gets the next value from the iterator over `a` every time it is called.